# Poisson distribution - adapting for different intervals

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution

Over a long period of time ,a plumber finds that on average he receives 2 emergency calls per week .Work out the probability of one emergency call on one day assuming the plumber is available for emergency calls five days a week .

I am getting 0.268 while answer is 0.938 .
Please help !?

Comment: maybe at least one?

Comment: At least once gives a probability of about $0.33$. Your answer appears to be right unless you forgot to mention any details in the problem. It's clear that you got your answer by finding $\mathsf P(X=1)$ where $X\sim\mathsf{Pois}\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)$. However, in the future, please show how you got your answer.

Comment: Thanks ,yes will show working in the future !

Comment: You should still edit to show how you got 0.268

Answer (score 1):

If $X_5 \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_5 = 2),$ and assuming that emergency calls tend to be spread evenly among days, then $X_1 \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda_1 = 2/5)$ describes the distribution of emergency calls on any one particular day.

Then using the Poisson PDF function `dpois` in R, we get $P(X_1 = 1) =0.2681$ and (as @remy says) $P(X_1 \ge 1) = 1 - P(X_1 = 0) = 0.3297.$

```
 dpois(1, 2/5)
 [1] 0.268128

 1 - dpois(0, 2/5)
 [1] 0.32968
```

Here is a bar graph (made with R) of the PDF of $\mathsf{Pois}(2/5).$

[image]

```
x=0:5;  pdf=dpois(x, 2/5)
plot(x, pdf, type="h", lwd=3, ylab="PDF", xlab="x", 
    ylim=c(0,max(pdf)), main="PDF of POIS(2/5)")
  abline(v=0, col="green2");  abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

*Note:* I've tried finding answers to several plausible (and some
not quite so plausible) alternative questions. It may be worthwhile to notice that $P(X_1 \le 1) = 0.3984.$ That would be the answer to "***at most 1*** emergency call on a particular day."

```
ppois(1, 2/5)
[1] 0.9384481
```

Comment: So the question should have been atmost 1 .

Comment: Not 'almost', but 'at most'. Not more than 1. $P(X_1 \le 1)$. Question as you have it makes sense. But 'at most 1' gets you the answer claimed.